# DTO (Data Transfer Object) implementation

Tags: dto

I have two questions about DTO implementation.

1. I have two apis return slightly different nested objects, which responses like:

```
    {
      "shop": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name", 
        "logo_url": "logo_url"
      }
      ...
    }
```

and

```
{
  "shop": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name", 
    "logo_url": "logo_url",
    "address": "...",
    "phone": "..."
  }
  ...
}
```

should I define `shop` as a inner class of each parent dto, or just define two different dto classes.

2. Some apis accept same dto object for both create and update, should I define just one class like `EditShopDTO` for both create and update, or define another two classes like `CreateShopDTO` and `UpdateShopDTO`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @Olivier Grégoire  java